# How access findViewById() outside Activity

Tags: java, android

How can I pass `findViewById` as parameter?

I would like create method:

```
public void makeText() {
    String random = randomize(); //example...
    TextView textView = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView);
    textView.setText(randomText);
}
```

But of course this method don't have function `findViewById`. Method `makeText` is outside `Activity` and `Fragment` classes.

Comment: You should pass an instance of `TextView` as a parameter. And then you can do `yourTextView.setText(randomText)`

Comment: Possible duplicate of [findViewById in non-Activity class](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25807205/findviewbyid-in-non-activity-class)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

you should pass activity instance to your class or method.

```
public void makeText(Activity activity) {
    String random = randomize(); //example...
    TextView textView = (TextView) activity.findViewById(R.id.textView);
    textView.setText(randomText);
}
```

Answer (score 3):

Passing activity's instance as a parameter is an antipattern and begging for memory leaks.

Rule of thumbs is: If you want to manipulate view, do it on UI layer (Activity/Fragment/Custom View etc), but don't pass them any further.

So if you want to edit text, inflate this view inside activity/fragment/whatsoever and pass to it a new value.

Answer (score 2):

First of all it is bad idea to edit controls properties beyond activity or fragment class. Passing context objects as Activity is also not the best idea, but I you must do it pass as argument ViewGroup which is the root of your view and call `findViewById` on it.

Personal I would recommend pass to method View you want to edit.

Comment: So how can I do it? I don't want repet code. In several activities I have this code, so I would like have it in one place.

Comment: Make base Activity/Fragment to inherit from it. After all I still don't see any case to make such global methods.